# MongoDb $and operator with geospatial queries

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a system in Java, part of which renders expressions from an internal representation to a MongoDb query. I render "AND" expressions the same way I render "OR" expressions. So if I have an expression like "category='GIBBLY' AND active=true", it would be rendered as:

`{$and:[{"category":"GIBBLY"},{"active":true}]}`

I understand that this isn't strictly necessary in this case. What I can't figure out is whether there is *ever* a case where $and is necessary (in my system, there will often be nested ANDs and ORs, if that makes any difference).

The reason this is an issue for me is that the $and operator seems to fail for geospatial queries. A query like this:

`{"$and":[{"loc":{"$nearSphere":[-79.75 , 43.5], "$maxDistance":0.00156787}}, {"active":true}]}`

fails with a "can't find special index: 2d" error. If I re-do the query as:

`{"loc":{"$nearSphere":[-79.75 , 43.5], "$maxDistance":0.00156787}, "active":true}`

it works fine.

I tried to do some research, and found a discussion of the issue [on the mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/RBew-fCz3hI), which referred to a discussion of [compound indexes in geospatial queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CompoundIndexes).

None of the information I found really explains why exactly $and doesn't work with the geospatial query. I have no compound indexes defined at all in my database, and the non-$and query works, so I'm not sure how $and works differently with respect to indexes.

To summarize, my questions are:

1. Is $and ever necessary, and if so, in what sorts of cases?
2. Does $and differ in some fundamental way from the implicit representation with respect to indexes?
3. Why exactly does $and not work with geospatial queries?

Comment: Does it error if the $nearSphere is the only condition in the $and?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572. I couldn't find any comments on it too.

Comment: Yes -- Same error if $nearSphere is the only condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is $and ever necessary, and if so, in what sorts of cases?

Here is the classic SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (x = 1 OR y = 0)
AND   (w = 1 OR z = 0)
```

Prior to the `$and` operator, this was very difficult to do. You could not do the following:

```
db.Table.find({$or: [{x:1},{y:0}] , $or: [{w:1},{z:0}]})
```

The query "looks" correct, but it is invalid JSON. You'll notice how I have two top-level `$or` keys. That comma is supposed to represent the "and", but it doesn't work in this case.

The `$and` operator is designed to solve this problem.

> Does $and differ in some fundamental way from the implicit representation with respect to indexes?

It should compile to the same basic query and use the same indexes. If not, this is definitely a bug.

> Why exactly does $and not work with geospatial queries?

The behaviour you are seeing is a probably a bug and should be reported: http://jira.mongodb.org/

Also, please not that MongoDB has special limits on Geospatial indexes. Your query may not be using indexing in an ideal fashion.

Comment: Thanks -- hadn't even thought about JSON map restrictions. I was looking for a way to see what MongoDb queries compile to, but couldn't find anything. As someone above mentioned, there's a ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572). So if you're reading this item because you're affected by the issue, be sure to upvote the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your first question, as you point out, using commas in queries is an implicit "and":

```
db.collection.find({name: "Jenna", number: 1})
```

The $and operator is necessary when you need to put multiple filters on a single field, which isn't possible using the comma syntax.  As an example, to find all documents with an array containing number 2 **and** number 10, you need the $and operator:

documents:

```
{_id: 1, array: [1, 10]}
{_id: 2, array: [2, 10]}
```

query:

```
> db.collection.find({$and: [{array: 2}, {array: 10}]})
{_id: 2, array: [2, 10]}
```

whereas the query without the $and operator only uses "array: 10" and returns both documents:

```
> db.collection.find({array: 2, array: 10})
{_id: 1, array: [1, 10]}
{_id: 2, array: [2, 10]}
```

Using the $and operator should have no impact with respect to indexes.  A single index will be used to meet the query.

Please feel free to up vote the JIRA ticket related to $and and geospatial queries if it impacts your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely lucid description. And crap -- that situation is going to occur constantly in my system (basically, "find all of the providers in this area who provide *all* of the following services"). I upvoted the ticket -- hopefully they'll make that work.

Comment: Could you show us an example of your query and your data? I think it may be possible to avoid the $add operator.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see your comment until just now. The problem query is basically something like the one in the original post. The real problem is the fact that the MongoDb queries are rendered from an expression system.

Comment: Luckily, the expression system requires AND and OR for any conjunction of operations, so it handles the situation you cited perfectly. The problem would be if I decided to have my expression render AND conjunctions implicitly.

My (hopefully temporary) solution was to handle the geospatial query in a custom way, and keep using the regular AND rendering for "normal" expressions.